# how do i get count of specific column used range

Tags: excel, vba

I want the count of specific column last used range,
In my case my column is ("F")  my data satrts from Range("F2") 
i tryed following code but i didnt get proper count

note = the Column dosent contains any blank data

```
xlwkbOutput.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate


    With ActiveSheet
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F2").End(xlDown)
    End With
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to find the last visible cell containing data in column F. Note that this is not neccessarily what Excel thinks is the last used cell in column F

```
xlwkbOutput.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    With ActiveSheet
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
```